# ControlTemplate Opacity not displayed like I want it to

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, opacity, controltemplate

I have a `Style` defined for my `DataGridCell`

```
<Style x:Key="MYDGCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MYDGCellControlTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity="0.3" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>                
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MYDGCellControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Grid x:Name="CellGrid">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Border>                
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="CellGrid">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush Opacity="2" StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Fuchsia" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="Transparent" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.8" Color="Transparent" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Fuchsia" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>                            
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

During Runtime I add additional `Triggers` for specific `Columns` like this in my Code

```
Style Sty = null;
if (Sty == null)
{
    Sty = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));                                
    Sty.BasedOn = (Style)Application.Current.TryFindResource("MYDGCellStyle");                                
}

DataTrigger t = new DataTrigger();
t.Binding = new Binding("ProductionStatus");
t.Value = "I";
Setter s = new Setter();
s.Property = DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty;
s.Value = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gold) { Opacity = 0.5 };
t.Setters.Add(s);

Sty.Triggers.Add(t);
DGC.CellStyle = Sty;
```

But if I focus one of the `Cell`s where a `DataTrigger` I added in my Code is triggerd the Color isn't displayed correctly.

How can I display the fuchsia Sides in front of the Gold Background?

Grey Cell Focused:

[image: Grey Cell Focused]

Gold Cell Focused:

[image: Gold Cell Focused]

**UPDATE**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MYDGCellControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">            
            <Grid>
            <Grid Grid.ZIndex="99"  x:Name="CellGrid"/>
            <Border Grid.ZIndex="98" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>            
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="CellGrid">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush Opacity="2" StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Fuchsia" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="#00FF00FF" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.9" Color="#00FF00FF" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Fuchsia" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>                            
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: So the problem is that if you focus a gold cell, fuchsia sides are displayed as orange kind, am I wrong?

Comment: No, you're right. I think that is because if I have an Opacity of 1 on my Gold the fuchsia sides can't be seen at all. If I set the Opacity to 0.1 the fuchsia sides are displayed correctly, but well the gold isn't really gold anymore.

Comment: So, which cell's color in the image is displayed correctly? E or l row in first set or second set?

Comment: The cell's color are all correct. But the fuchsia sides in the second Picture are wrong. They should look the same as in the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be, that you apply a golden color brush **above** the fuchsia edges, so they get tinted by 50% of gold.

```
s.Value = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gold) { Opacity = 0.5 };
```

Additionally you should be aware that using `Transparent` in XAML means "white with no opacity", so if you want to fade out funchsia you should not fade to transparent white, but to transparent fuchsia instead.

```
White:               #FFFFFFFF
Transparent:         #00FFFFFF
Fuchsia opaque:      #FFFF00FF
Fuchsia transparent: #00FF00FF
```

To enforce the z-order you could use an additional container around the item given and apply the status here "during runtime". Anyway this will not be an MVVM approach.

The better way might be to define a custom template-parameter (`bool IsSpecificColumn`) in your XAML, which will be set in your code "during runtime". Using `MultiTrigger` you can also define a third state for gold+fuchsia.

If you have to combine even more states you should let WPF do the job and use the approach with the boxed containers mentioned above together with template-parameters.

Comment: Yes I have also identified that as my Problem. But how can I apply the golden color brush **under** the fuchsia edges? I need my standard Style in my App.xaml but also to add new Trigger during Runtime.

Comment: I tought I already did the Approach with the container. Because I have a Grid around the Border. The Border is TemplateBining and the fuchsia is on the Grid above the Border.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new "IsFocused" trigger in your new style(I ProductionStatus)like this:

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="CellGrid">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush Opacity="2" StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Fuchsia" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="Gold" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.8" Color="Gold" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Fuchsia" />
             </LinearGradientBrush>                            
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

I know you are doing it on code behind, but I think you'll understand me(easyer to copy-paste).