# Focused Cell in Row isn't displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, triggers, controltemplate

I have a `Style` for my `DataGridRow` and `DataGridCell`. In my RowStyle I change the Background of the selected `Row` and in my CellStyle I change the Background of my focused `Cell`. This works when I first click in a new `Row`. But if I click on another `Cell` in the same `Row`, the `Style` isn't applied. If I change the `Cell` with my Arrow-Keys it works, not if I click with the Mouse. On my `DataGrid` I have `SelectionMode` = Single.

```
<!--DataGridRow-->
    <Style x:Key="MYDGRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">            
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />-->           
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Grid x:Name="RowGridTop">
                        <Grid Grid.ZIndex="89" x:Name="RowGrid"/>
                            <Border
                                    Grid.ZIndex="88"
                                    x:Name="DGR_Border"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid x:Name="selectiveScrollingGrid">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <!--<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />-->
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <DataGridCellsPresenter x:Name="dataGridCellsPresenter" Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                            Focusable="True" />
                                    <DataGridRowHeader x:Name="dataGridRowHeader" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                        Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, 
                                        ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}}"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="Details" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                        <DataGridDetailsPresenter x:Name="dataGridDetailsPresenter" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            </Border>                            
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">                                
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="dataGridDetailsPresenter" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="RowGrid" Value="{DynamicResource Brush_DataGridSelected}" />                                
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>            
    </Style>
    <!--DataGridRow-->



    <!--DataGridCell-->
    <Style x:Key="MYDGCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MYDGCellControlTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity="0.3" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>                
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MYDGCellControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">            
            <Grid>
            <Grid Grid.ZIndex="99"  x:Name="CellGrid"/>
            <Border Grid.ZIndex="98" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>            
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="CellGrid" Value="{DynamicResource Brush_DataGridCellFocused}" />                                     
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>        
    <!--DataGridCell-->
```

If I target 'RowGridTop' in my `Trigger` the focused `Cell` is correctly displayed but the `ZIndex` isn't correct. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517397/controltemplate-opacity-not-displayed-like-i-want-it-to) is shown why I need the 
additional `Grid`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did it. I had to change the `ZIndex` so that the ones on the DataGridRowStyle were higher than the one on the DataGridCellStyle. And I also had to set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on my "RowGrid" `Grid`.